# how to make two classes interact

Tags: python, class, oop

Let's say I have these two classes:

```
class Order:
    def __init__(self, dish, status):
        self.dish = dish
        self.status = status
    def cook(self):
        self.status = 'cooking'
    def serve(self):
        self.status = 'served'
```

and

```
class Orders:
    def __init__(self, all_orders):
        self.lst = all_orders
        self.waiting = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='waiting']
        self.cooking = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='cooking']
        self.served = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='sevred']
    @property
    def on_it(self):
        return f"{len(self.cooking)} orders are being prepared"
    @property
    def done(self):
        return f"{len(self.served)} orders have been served"
    @property
    def to_go(self):
        return f"{len(self.waiting)} orders to go"
    @property
    def progress(self):
        percentage = round(self.done / len(self.lst) * 100)
        return f"{percentage} % of all orders have been served"
```

Now let's say I've created an instance of `Orders` with a whole lot of orders:

```
orders = Orders([Order('pasta carbonara', 'waiting'),
                 Order('latkes', 'waiting'),
                 Order('chocolate lava cake', 'waiting')
                 ... and so on])
```

Now, each time an order in `orders` gets served, I would like the two lists of the `Orders` instance to become reorganized so that the `Order` instance in question (let's say we just started making the pasta) gets popped from `orders.waiting` and appended to `orders.cooking`. Likewise, when served, it moves from `orders.cooking` and added to `orders.served`. This, in turn, will affect `orders.done`, `orders.on_it`, `orders.to_go` and `orders.progress` properties when I call them in between servings.

So, basically, I would want the printed output of the following code to keep changing with each step as each order gets cooked and served:

```
for order in orders:
    order.cook()
    print(orders.done)
    print(orders.on_it)
    print(orders.to_go)
    print(orders.progress)
    print()
    order.serve()
    print(orders.done)
    print(orders.on_it)
    print(orders.to_go)
    print(orders.progress)
    print()
```

I imagine that to achieve this I'd need to connect the two classes in some way and then add something to the Order.serve() function. Is there a way to do this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic possibilities:

1. always explicitely update the `Orders`::

   ```
    class Orders:
        def __init__(self, all_orders):
            self.lst = all_orders
            self.update()
        def update(self):
            """
            call update() after one or more order status changes
            and before accessing this Order object.
            """
            self.waiting = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='waiting']
            self.cooking = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='cooking']
            self.served = [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='served']
        ...
   ```
2. dynamically create the lists when needed, e.g.

   ```
    class Orders:
        ...
        @property
        def waiting(self):
             return [o for o in self.lst if o.status=='waiting']
   ```

   this is more convenient, but may cause some unnecessary computation. That should not be a problem unless there is a really large number of orders with frequent changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change each of your sub-lists into functions/properties that return the lists without assigning to attributes.

Then, each time the function is called, it'll re-filter the order list with the current Order statuses